# CompareTo() method in Java

Tags: java

//I know that `compareTo()` returns an int value.

```
 returns 0 if a equal b
 returns -1 if a < b
 returns 1 if a > b
```

//But how does sort method makes use of these 0, 1, -1 values, and how does it arranges the list exactly.

Comment: It doesn't necessary have to return always these values (-1 and 1). For example, `"a".compareTo("d") == -3`. _"a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object."_

Comment: if compareTo(e1, e2) < 0 then e1 should be to the left of e2

Comment: @Sotirios , as compareTo method takes two object comparison, does it mean it takes one at 0 index and then compares it with others, or does it take different one every time.

Comment: No. The sorting methods uses the `Comparator`. **It** knows about the indices of the elements.

Comment: @Sotirios , does it use Comparator when we implement Comparable not Comparator because I implemented Comparable in my class so thatz why!!

Comment: Depends which sort method you use. If you use one that takes a `Comparator`, it will use the `Comparator`. If you use the one that doesn't, it will attempt to use the `Comparable` interface which your objects should be implementing.

Comment: How a specific data structure uses a comparator depends on the data structure in question entirely

Comment: @Arkadiy , does it take e1, e2 first at index 0 and 1 and then move on to index 2 and 3 next.

Comment: @Sotirios, correct me if I am wrong, so it means that if I implement Comparable interface in my class, sort method that uses Comparable , on calling sort method compareTo method will be called automatically and in the compare To method the attribute will be checked based on which we want to do sort the list.If this part is correct then for what sort method needs values like 0 , 1 and -1 .

Comment: If I compare two elements, with `Comparator`, and the method returns a negative value, I know the first argument is smaller (in terms of the sort) than the second. So in my resulting list, I will put the first argument before the second (depending on the order you want).

Comment: Different soring algorithms compare different locations in different order. Naive buble sort would compare 0 to 1, then 1 to 2 and so on. A sophisticated algorithm would compare very different pairs of elements - most likely not elements next to each other in the original sequence. At different stages in the comparison process different elements are compared.

Comment: @Arkadiy so we can say simply that sort() method uses those values 0, 1, -1 for any kind of internal sort it does to sort our list!!

Comment: @Sotirios  so we can say simply that sort() method uses those values 0, 1, -1 for any kind of internal sort it does to sort our list!!

Comment: Yes, but note that it's `0`, a negative or a positive value, not necessarily `-1` and `1`.

Comment: @Sotirios yeah I know that and thanks for helping, goodbye!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort an array with compareTo(),

```
public void sort(Comparable[] lst)
{
    for(int i=0; i<lst.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i; j<lst.length; j++)
        {
            if(lst[i].compareTo(lst[j]) < 0)
            {
                //swap elements, sorts in ascending order
                Comparable tmp = lst[i];
                lst[i] = lst[j];
                lst[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, [here's the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/TimSort.java#TimSort.binarySort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2Cjava.util.Comparator%29), not sure what more you want. Collections.sort seems to ultimately call this.

```
private static <T> void binarySort(T[] a, int lo, int hi, int start, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    assert lo <= start && start <= hi;
    if (start == lo)
        start++;
    for ( ; start < hi; start++) {
        T pivot = a[start];
        // Set left (and right) to the index where a[start] (pivot) belongs
        int left = lo;
        int right = start;
        assert left <= right;
        /*
         * Invariants:
         *   pivot >= all in [lo, left).
         *   pivot <  all in [right, start).
         */
        while (left < right) {
            int mid = (left + right) >>> 1;
            if (c.compare(pivot, a[mid]) < 0)
                right = mid;
            else
                left = mid + 1;
        }
        assert left == right;
        /*
         * The invariants still hold: pivot >= all in [lo, left) and
         * pivot < all in [left, start), so pivot belongs at left.  Note
         * that if there are elements equal to pivot, left points to the
         * first slot after them -- that's why this sort is stable.
         * Slide elements over to make room for pivot.
         */
        int n = start - left;  // The number of elements to move
        // Switch is just an optimization for arraycopy in default case
        switch (n) {
            case 2:  a[left + 2] = a[left + 1];
            case 1:  a[left + 1] = a[left];
                     break;
            default: System.arraycopy(a, left, a, left + 1, n);
        }
        a[left] = pivot;
    }
}
```

Comment: If DV is due to formatting issues those are fixed. Otherwise please explain.

Comment: u r showing it based on Comparator interface, does the same apply to comparable interface because compareTo method is in Comparable interface and that is what i implemented in my class.

Comment: @Aamir Browse the source for yourself and see.